# How to escape special characters using Mongo regex in PHP format

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

I have tried below lines of code to get result of matching hotel name using Mongo regex in PHP format. But am not getting how to escape special characters:

```
$filter_array = array_merge($filter_array,
array('name' => array('$regex' => new MongoRegex("/".$hotel_name."/i"))));
```

Through this I am getting output for matching hotels but if suppose hotel name is like "ABC ( 3 Stars)" then am unable to get result for this kind of hotels as this hotel name is having special character "(" and ")".

How to escape such special character in hotel name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems it uses PCRE style expressions, in that case [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) is used:

```
new MongoRegex("/".preg_quote($hotel_name, '/')."/i")
```

Comment: But I need to escape "(" and ")" in hotel name = "ABC ( 3 star )"

Comment: @pihu it will do that

Comment: @pihu It will escape not only `(` and `)` but also other special chars, plus `/`, which is made special by using it as delimiter.